# What is the name of this purple-flowered climbing plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants, growth

I bought this plant today, it has purple flowers and it climbs.
[image]

[image]

I forget to ask the seller about its name and I regret it! Any recommendation on how to care for this plant? Should I keep it in a shady or sunny spot?

Comment: Looks like a legume. Any chance you can get  pick of the flowers?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't have any flowers currently :(. It's for decoration only it doesn't have fruit

Comment: Could you tell us where you are in the world, and if it was sold to you as a houseplant or for outdoors? Thanks!

Comment: I'm living in Bahrain and it's sold for outdoors

Comment: It's certainly imported not a native plant.

Comment: I'd take an educated guess at Akebia quinata...though this one's not in full, lush growth, looks more like its in a winter state.

Comment: @Bamboo Akebia quinata appears to have leaves that meet together at one point like an umbrella tree's leaves do. This plant here does not.

Comment: I don't know what it is, but it looks more closely related to a blueberry bush, or a nightshade, insofar as leaf structure goes. I would guess it's something else, though.

Comment: @Shule - we're stabbing in the dark really, not enough growth to tell what it really is. Not even any evidence of twining or tendril growth - and no fruit might just mean no edible fruit.

Comment: @Bamboo That's fine. I didn't mean to devalue your guess. I just noticed something and thought it might help identify it.

Comment: @Shule - s'ok, I don't feel devalued!

Comment: This is definitely a legume. But as the legume family holds the third most species to that of any other plant family, identification of leaves alone is impossible. We will need to see a flower for a positive specific identification. Perhaps Desmodium rotundifolium? But again, I could keep guessing and guessing on leaves alone.

Answer (score 1):

On the surface of it looks like gokarna (a local Indian name for [*Clitoria ternatea*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitoria_ternatea))

Comment: Welcome to the site Parth! We appreciate your answer! In order to make it complete, and helpful to others, we need to know what makes you think that, including a reference to where you got your information. In this form, it's likely to be deleted. If that happens, feel free to post it again with the required information. Don't be discouraged though, we just do things a little differently than you might be used to. Everything's explained in our [help]. Hope to see you again!

Comment: I added this link because searching for "gokarna flower" takes me to the Wikipedia page for Clitorea ternatea. If that's not correct, please update your post with the correct link. Don't forget to add an explanation of **why** your identification is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

it is [*Akebia quinata*](http://www.imagejuicy.com/images/plants/a/akebia/3/)...commonly known as five leaf akebia.

Comment: Looks correct but can you add to this answer to the information is not just in the link?

Comment: Actually, I doubt this. Bamboo and shule discussed this in the comments above: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akebia_quinata) states "compound leaves with five leaflets", this specimen's leaf cluster does not originate from one point and the second picture shows one with seven leaflets on a stem.